# (iphone) i'm getting black rectangle behind image, why?

Tags: iphone, shadow, layer

I have UIImageView subclass instance which has multiple image sublayers.

I want to add/remove shadow dynamically to this view.

The following code works fine(imageView subclass's implementation) for a imageView with one sublayer, but shows black rectangle instead of shadow for a imageView with multiple sublayers.

(actually, for one layer image, the code seems to keep adding shadow on top of previous shadow if run multiple times, but this is a minor problem)

```
- (void) drawLayer: (CALayer*) layer inContext: (CGContextRef)context
{   
    SYSLOG(LOG_DEBUG, "in drawLayer, isShadowed: %d", isShadowed);

    if(isShadowed == true)
    {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);
        CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(10, 10), 3);
        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL);
        [layer renderInContext:context];
        CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
    else
    {
        [layer renderInContext:context];
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your layer's `opaque` is not NO, CGContextClearRect paints black rather than punching a transparent hole in the layer. I'm guessing that's the problem.